# Import an excel sheet containing images in c#

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

I have an excel file containing one integer, one string and one image column. Sheet contains many such records. I am able to import data without image column but am unaware of how to retrieve image column.

Comment: "excel file" what format? can you export it as tsv or csv?

Comment: Do you want to access the images or ignore them?  How are you accessing Excel?  Which Excel format are you using, and what have you tried so far?

Comment: @Poonam: In case you have hyperlinks in the image, you can use System.Net Namespace to download the image from the Web using webclient and then upload the file.